# How do I trigger methods in a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm refactoring to remove logic from my WPF window's code-behind and to conform to MVVM.  My ViewModel calls a method from my DataService class to get Employee data from the database and map it onto objects, then return the objects as an IList.  It also contains a method for filtering the list by DepartmentID.

```
public class EmployeesViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
    public IList<EmployeeModel> allEmployees = (IList<EmployeeModel>)EmployeeDataService.GetEmployeeList();
    public List<EmployeeModel> employeesByDepartment = new List<EmployeeModel>();

    private List<EmployeeModel> getEmployeesByDepartment(List<EmployeeModel> employees, int departmentID)
        {
        employeesByDepartment = (List<EmployeeModel>)employees.Where(employees => employees.Department.ID == departmentID);
        return employeesByDepartment;
        }
    }
```

How do I execute these functions without using an event in the code behind of my main window?

Comment: `ICommand` [Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) as `Click` events replacement. To publish data on the View you may use properties and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for it.

Comment: Having code-behind does not violate MVVM. Although, in most cases avoiding it leads to clean code. But it has nothing to do with being compliant with MVVM. MVVM and code-behind are independent concepts (the former is a design pattern, while the latter is a compiler feature). Both can be combined perfectly. As already suggested by aepot, you should make use of the commanding pattern: [Commanding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to move your event from the code-behind to a property in your ViewModel. It is not uncommon to chain methods onto the PropertyChanged event of your ViewModel to make it perform an action when the value of a data-bound property changes.  I do this frequently.

Example: Let's say that you want to show employees by department if they toggle on a UI Checkbox "Show By Dept" that is bound to a `bool ShowByDept` property in your ViewModel.

```
public class EmployeesViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

private bool showByDept;
public bool ShowByDept { get => showByDept; set { showByDept = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }

public EmployeesViewModel()
{
    PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;
}

private void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ShowByDept))
    {
        // Trigger: If the user toggled on the "Show By Dept" checkbox, then run this method.
        if (ShowByDept)
        {
            // Execute this method
            YourMethod();
        }
    }
}

...
}
```

Comment: I see.  So, in my implementation, the GridView would be empty until the user selected a department from the combobox.  That would trigger the PropertyChanged event, which executes the sql query, which provides a datasource for the grid.  Do I have that right?

Comment: What about Commands?

Comment: @JoshuaWhite yes, that would work. Keep in mind that what triggers the method that you wish to execute should come from either a bounded public property (int, bool, string, class, etc.) or a bounded public Command property (very common for various Button or click-based event types).  The point is to try and keep your logic in the ViewModel, instead of the code-behind.

Comment: @aepot Yes, Command bindings are very common, and are also a good way to keep you  logic and methods inside of the VIewModel, instead of the code-behind.  The same principle applies: Let your data binding get you into the ViewModel, then let the VIewModel find its way to the method you wish to execute (thus, eliminating the need for code-behind).

Comment: ICommand would be the right solution. It's not _"also a good way"_, but the better way. Additionally, your pattern relies on property changes. If you want to start an operation, that does not depend on a property or its value actually changing, then you are stuck (it can only get ugly from here). You can do many things, but ICommand is the only good and clean solution in this scenario. Switching on properties to decide which branch to take adds unnecessary cyclomatic complexity and makes your code ugly and difficult. This should be your last resort.